# Как поставить пробел только перед заглавной буквой?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задание, в котором сказано что даётся кортеж с ФИО, но там нету пробелов. Надо поставить пробел перед каждой заглавной буквой(кроме первой). Сам смог сделать только такой **Код**:

```
import re

i = 0
с = ['АлександровДенисПетрович']
while i < len(c):
    s = c[i]
    s = re.sub(r' *([ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ]) *', r' \1 ', s)  # оставляет ровно по одному пробелу до/после
    c[i] = s[1:]
    i+=1

print(c)
```

Но к сожалению пробелы ставятся и после заглавной буквы.

```
['А лександров Д енис П етрович']
```

Как поставить пробелы только ***перед ЗАГЛАВНЫМИ*** буквами?

Comment: Просто напишите r' \1' вместо r' \1 '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант решения без регулярок и без перечисления букв. У строк есть метод `isupper`, которым можно проверить относится ли буква к верхнему регистру:

```py
name = 'АлександровДенисПетрович'


result = name[0]
for letter in name[1:]:
    if letter.isupper():
        result += f' {letter}'
    else:
        result += letter

print(result)
```

Comment: @Эникейщик почему? Я же первую букву исключил из цикла и сразу записал в result как есть.

Comment: А, точно. Не обратил внимания.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве прикола:

```
s = 'АлександровДенисПетрович'

print(''.join(s[j]if j not in[i for i in range(len(s))if s[i]!=s.lower()[i]] else ' '+s[j]for j in range(len(s))).lstrip())
```